# How to save network configuration in android-x86

Tags: networking, configuration, android-x86

After android-x86 loaded in VirtualBox I am configuring network(for Bridge):

```
route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
setprop net.dns1 192.168.0.1
```

All goes fine but I don't want to write this commands any time I load virtual machine. Is there any way to write this commands in some config or somthing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the end of /etc/init.sh